# Input type number not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

My form has the following field:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="num_auto_tests">Automated Tests</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="num_auto_tests" placeholder="0">
</div>
```

Clearly, I set `input type="number"`. However, when I do:

`typeof($("#num_auto_tests).val())` it returns `string` - which is messing up my calculations. Is there anything I can do make it "truly" a number?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just do `var numAutoTests = parseFloat($('#num_auto_tests').val());`.

Comment: `.val()` always returns a string, it says so in the jQuery documentation. Use `parseInt()` to convert it to a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wanting to make sure that the value is cast as an integer. use `parseInt()` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

#### HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="num_auto_tests">Automated Tests</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="num_auto_tests" placeholder="0">
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var value = parseInt( $( '#num_auto_tests' ).val() );

</script>
```

If you want to allow for decimal places rather than forcing an integer, you can use `parseFloat()` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var value = parseFloat( $( '#num_auto_tests' ).val() );

</script>
```

Last option would be using the `Number()` function - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var value = Number( $( '#num_auto_tests' ).val() );

</script>
```

Comment: If you're using `parseInt` adding the radix is generally considered a good idea.

Comment: It's not a good idea to quote `w3schools.com`. Kindly look at http://w3fools.com.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, the value of a text field is a `string`. You need to perform type conversion to convert to a number.

There are two methods for this. `Number()` and `parseInt()`. Here's an example

```
typeof(Number($("#num_auto_tests").val()));
=> number
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you can also coerce a string to a number by prepending a plus sign.

```
typeof(+($("#num_auto_tests").val()));
```

Try it in your console

```
+("45")
=> 45
```

Comment: You could also bang a `+` in front of the string too to coerce it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Perhaps a bit more eloquently than I did :)

Comment: I've started to use the + to convert string to numbers lately.  Just keep in mind that using the + to convert empty string ("") gives you a zero.  Something to be aware of.

Comment: The problem with using the unary + operator is that it is hard to read in that it does not clearly express intent like parseInt does for instance

Answer (score 0):

Please consider parsing it to an Integer:

```
typeof parseInt($("#num_auto_tests").val(), 10);
=> number
```

You can use `parseFloat()` if you are dealing with decimals.

Answer (score 0):

what is happening, is that you are resricting what type of input the user can 'input', it will look different from input type text.
However, when you use JQuery to get the value, you get a string representation of it. If you need to use the number you need to parse it doing either:

```
var num = parseFloat($('#num_auto_tests').val())
```

or

```
var num = parseFloat($('#num_auto_tests').val())
```